# Auto incrementing a foreign key value the same as the primary key of the parent table in SQL when inserting data?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, primary-key, constraint

I have the following two connected tables as shown below in the Microsoft SQL Server.

When inserting data from visual studio, the **foreign key** in the Reservations table (**Customer_ID**) should be auto incremented and have the same value as the **Primary key** of the parent table Customer_Info (**Customer_ID**).

Should i do it via the SQL Statements in Visual Studio or it is possible to be done directly in the Database? How can i do it? Thanks

[image]

Visual Studio Windows Forms App Design:

[image]

The SQL Statement when button is clicked:

```
 var query = "insert into Customer_info(Customer_Name,Customer_Phone) " +
            "values('" + name + "','" + phone + "');" +
            " insert into Reservations(RV_DAY,Customer_ID,Table_Arrangement,RV_OT,RV_PW,RV_SIOC) " +
            "values('" + day + "',50,'" + tb + "','" + SR1 + "','" + SR2 + "','" + SR3 + "');";
```

Visual Studio Exception error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have a slight misunderstanding of how these relationships works.

For the parent table, `Customer_Info`, your insert statements will look like this:

```
INSERT INTO Customer_Info
  (Customer_Name, Customer_Phone)
VALUES
  ('csandreas1', '555-5555');
```

Notice I didn't include the CustomerID field.  As long as you have this set as an IDENTITY field, it will be auto-incremented in the way you describe.

Now here's an insert for the child table, Reservations:

```
INSERT INTO Reservations
  (RV_DAY, Customer_ID, Table_Arrangement, RV_OT, RV_PW, RV_SIOC)
VALUES
  ('', 5, '', '', '', '');
```

*Note that I left all the other columns blank but Customer_ID, only because I don't really know what they are.*

So, when inserting into the Reservations table, you will need to explicitly indicate which `Customer_Info` row is associated with that reservation.

SQL Server will validate during the insert process that there is really a row in Customer_Info with an ID of 5.

---

Regarding your code, you will need to execute the insert into Customer_Info first, and then get the resulting generated CustomerID, and *then* insert into the Reservation table.

You can get the inserted value using the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` T-SQL function.  In your example code above, you would replace "50" with "SCOPE_IDENTITY()" to insert the CustomerID for the just-added customer record.

---

As a VERY IMPORTANT side note regarding your .NET code, you should *never* concatenate user input with SQL strings.  Use a SqlCommand object and then add parameters.  There are many examples of this online, check one out [here](https://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06).

Doing what you're doing opens you up to the risk of [SQL Injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).